# AngularJS: Confuse about object reference in $scope

Tags: angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <h1 ng-click="click()">{{person.name}}</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        var p = $scope.person = {
            name: 'Br'
        };

        $scope.click = function () {
            p = {};
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the `<h1>`, I reset the `p` object, so I expect empty in the `h1` tag.

Because I think the variable `p` has the same reference as `$scope.person`, which point to the same object.

In fact nothing changed when I clicked, only if I reset the `$scope.person = {}`.

So why it doesn't work as I expect? What's wrong in my thought?

Comment: p is just a pointer. Physically p = {} creates object {} somewhere in memory and put in 'p' object address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not related to Angular but how object are manipulated in JavaScript.

You're right when you say that `p` and `$scope.person` both reference to the same object in memory.

However when you write `p = {}` you are not touching the object that `p` was pointing to, you are having `p` reference a new object, hence it is not `$scope.person` anymore.

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
a === b; // true
b = {};
a === b; // false
```

If you want to remove the `name` property of `p`/`$scope.person` you can write

```
delete p.name; // this will also delete $scope.person.name
```